# What does "$R^2$ estimates the combined dispersion against the single dispersion of the observed and predicted series" mean?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, goodness-of-fit, regression-coefficients

In a paper I came across the description of $R^2$ as "it estimates the combined dispersion against the single dispersion of the observed and predicted series". I am not able to understand this statement. I understand that $R^2$ is the square of the correlation coefficient of predicted and observed values.

Answer (score 1):

[Dispersion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) broadly refers to how broad or narrow a distribution (either theoretical or observed) stretches. Variance is a common measure of dispersion.

$R^2$ has another interpretation as the [percentage of variance explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_explained_variance):

> In this form $R^2$ is expressed as the ratio of the explained variance (variance of the model's predictions, which is $SS_{reg} / n$) to the total variance (sample variance of the dependent variable, which is $SS_{tot} / n$).

It seems (without further context) that the authors of your paper are reporting the $R^2$ as a [measure of model fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Interpretation):

> $R^2$ is a statistic that will give some information about the goodness of fit of a model. In regression, the $R^2$ coefficient of determination is a statistical measure of how well the regression line approximates the real data points. An $R^2$ of 1 indicates that the regression line perfectly fits the data.

If one takes "combined dispersion" in the quotation to refer to the dispersion of observed values, "combined" referring to both modeled values and residual error not accounted for in the model, and "single dispersion" to refer to the dispersion of the modeled series, then "observed and predicted series" correspond to $SS_{tot}/n$ and $SS_{tot}/n$ above.

Comment: What do you suppose the terms "combined dispersion," "single dispersion," "observed ... series," and "predicted series" mean in the quotation and how does your understanding fit with the explanation of $R^2$ you have provided in your answer?

Comment: @whuber Respectively, I took each to mean: the dispersion of observed values, "combined" referring to both modeled and residual; the dispersion of the modeled series; the observed series of data at hand in the paper; the predictions of the paper's model. $R^2$ measures the variances of the modeled series and observed series, with variance being a measure of dispersion. Did I err in my interpretation of the context?

Comment: I don't know, and don't wish to suggest, that you erred. The trouble with the quotation is that it might mean many things, so I was trying to encourage you to amplify your answer a little so that it addresses these uncertainties more directly.

Comment: @whuber A valid suggestion! I'm new to CV & SO, and seem to err on the side of brevity. I've edited the answer to be more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to our site, then, and thank you for your contributions!